# Finite Difference equations - slow computations

Tags: difference-equations, finite-difference-method

The following code I have written runs very slow, in fact, so slow that it does not finish computation.

```
alpha = 0.50;
xmin = 1;
xmax = 15;
xdivisions = 14;
dx = (xmax - xmin)/xdivisions;
xgrid = Range[xmin, xmax, dx];
U = Array[u, xdivisions + 1, {xmin, xmax}];
a[x_] := -1;
b[x_] := -(3/x);
c[x_] := 1;
d[x_] := -1.5;
e[x_] := alpha/2;
aGrid = Map[a,xgrid];
bGrid = Map[b,xgrid];
cGrid = Map[c,xgrid];
dGrid = Map[d,xgrid];
eGrid = Map[e,xgrid];
dudx = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], xgrid, U];
dudx2 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], xgrid,U];
uleft = NSolve[dudx[[1]] == 0, U[[1]]];
uright = NSolve[U[[-1]] == 0, U[[-1]]];
boundary = Join[uleft[[1]], uright[[1]]];
equations = Map[(0 == #) &, Flatten[Table[aGrid[[i]]*dudx2[[i]] + 

bGrid[[i]]*dudx[[i]] + cGrid[[i]]*U[[i]] + dGrid[[i]]*(U[[i]]^2) + eGrid[[i]]*(U[[i]]^3), {i, 1, Length[xgrid]}] /. boundary]];
intSol = NSolve[equations, U[[2 ;; Length[xgrid] - 1]]][[1]]
```

The problem is with the final line of code. The fifteen finite difference equations just don't finish giving an output! :(

Edit:

Thanks for the help with that part of the question.

I would like to ask a small further question.

I appended the following to the end of my code. For some reason, my laptop's again taking forever to finish computations.

```
intSol = FindRoot[equations[[;; Length[xgrid] - 2]], Map[{#, 1} &, Apply[ Union, Map[Variables, equations [[All, 2]] ] ] ]];
boundarySol = (boundary /. intSol);
solutionArray = (U /. intSol) /. boundarySol;
dataPoints = Table[{xmin + i*dx, ymin + j*dy, solutionArray[[i + 1, j + 1]]}, {i, 0, Length[xgrid] - 1}, {j, 0, Length[ygrid] - 1}];
ListPlot3D[Flatten[dataPoints, 1], AxesLabel -> {Style[x, Medium, Blue], Style[y, Medium, Blue], Style[u, Medium, Blue]}, PlotRange -> All];
```

Any help would be very nice.

Comment: It seems you have 15 equations and 13 variables

Comment: I omitted the first and last equations from the penultimate line of code. Having done that, once I run the code, all my other laptop functions freeze. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solves your first 13 equations (you have 13 variables)

```
s = FindRoot[equations[[;; 13]], {#, 1} &/@ Union@@ (Variables /@ equations[[All, 2]])]
(*
{u[2] -> 0.763932, u[3] -> 0.763932, u[4] -> 0.763932, 
 u[5] -> 0.763932, u[6] -> 0.763932, u[7] -> 0.763932, 
 u[8] -> 0.763932, u[9] -> 0.763932, u[10] -> 0.76393, 
 u[11] -> 0.763907, u[12] -> 0.763604, u[13] -> 0.759619, 
 u[14] -> 0.706721}
*)
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell why my first method did not work?

Comment: @failexam Probably because `NSolve[ ]` uses the symbolic form while `FindRoot[ ]` is purely numeric